# Linked List - Skip M nodes, delete N nodes after that

Tags: java, linked-list, nullpointerexception, singly-linked-list

I am trying to solve this code challenge:

> The target is to Traverse a Linked List and skip M nodes, then delete N nodes after that, and then skip M nodes again, and then delete N nodes after that, repeating this until the end of the linked list.
>
> #### Example
>
> **Input:**
>
> - Linked List: 1->2->3->4->5->6->7->8->null
> - M: 2
> - N: 2
>
> **Expected output:**
>
> - 1->2->5->6->null

#### My attempt

I have made a function `skipMdeleteN` to do that task.

```
public class LinkedList{
    public static class Node{
        int data;
        Node next;
        public Node(int data){
            this.data=data;
            this.next=null;
        }
    }
    public static Node head;
    public static Node tail;

    public Node addFirst(int data){
        Node newNode=new Node(data);
        if(head==null){
            head=newNode;
            return head;
        }
        newNode.next=head;
        head=newNode;
        return head;
    }

    public static void print(LinkedList ll){
        Node temp=head;
        while(temp!=null){
            System.out.print(temp.data+"->");
            temp=temp.next;
        }
        System.out.print("null");
    } 

    //Delete N Nodes After M Nodes of a Linked List
    public static void skipMdeleteN(int M, int N, Node head){
        Node curr=head;
        Node ptr;
        for(int temp=1;temp<=M;temp++){
            curr=curr.next;
            if(temp==M){
                ptr=curr.next;
                for(int temp2=1;temp2<N;temp2++){
                    ptr=ptr.next;
                    if(temp2==N){
                        curr.next=ptr.next;
                        curr=ptr.next;
                    }
                } temp=1;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        LinkedList ll=new LinkedList();
        head=ll.addFirst(8);
        head=ll.addFirst(7);
        head=ll.addFirst(6);
        head=ll.addFirst(5);
        head=ll.addFirst(4);
        head=ll.addFirst(3);
        head=ll.addFirst(2);
        head=ll.addFirst(1);
        
        
        print(ll);
        int M=2; int N=2;
        ll.skipMdeleteN(M,N,head);
        print(ll);
    }
}
```

#### The problem

I get this exception:

```
1->2->3->4->5->6->7->8->nullException in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read field "next" because "<local4>" is null
        at LinkedList.skipMdeleteN(LinkedList.java:42)
        at LinkedList.main(LinkedList.java:66)
```

Comment: It should be really easy to debug such problems. Have you used a debugger, and set break points and inspected variables? What were your findings?

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in this code:

- The reason of the error is that your loop executes `temp=1;` once the deletion has taken place, and this makes the outer loop continue forever, and eventually `curr` will be `null` and `curr.next;` will trigger the exception.
- You are mixing *instance* and *static* stuff. Although you create an *instance* with `new LinkedList`, you then continue to use static methods and variables... this is wrong. Once you have created `ll`, that `ll` should have instance members that manage the state of *that parcticular* list. So `head` should not be `static`, nor your methods (except `main`), nor the `Node` class, ...
- There is no protection in your code against running outside of the linked list, for instance when the values of `N` or `M` are much larger than the size of your linked list.
- There is no provision in your code to update `head` to `null` in case `M` is zero and `N` is not.
- Not a problem, but it is more common to use camelCase for variables, so name `n` and `m` as lowercase.

Here is a correction of your code:

```java
public class LinkedList {
    public class Node{ // Not static
        int data;
        Node next;
        public Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = null;
        }
    }
    public Node head; // Not static
    public Node tail; // Not static

    public void addFirst(int data) { // Not static, and void
        Node newNode = new Node(data);
        newNode.next = head;
        head = newNode;
    }

    public void print() { // Not static
        Node temp = head;
        while (temp != null) {
            System.out.print(temp.data+"->");
            temp=temp.next;
        }
        System.out.println("null");
    }

    // Following method should not be static, and not have head parameter
    public void skipMdeleteN(int m, int n) {
        if (n <= 0 || head == null) return; // Nothing to remove
        if (m == 0) { // Remove everything
            head = null;
            return; 
        }

        Node curr = head;
        while (curr != null) {
            for (int temp = 1; temp < m; temp++) {
                curr = curr.next;
                if (curr == null) return; // Nothing more to remove
            }
    
            Node ptr = curr;
            for (int temp = 0; temp <= n; temp++) {
                curr = curr.next;
                if (curr == null) break; // Prevent invalid access
            }
            ptr.next = curr; // Perform the removal
        }
    }
        
    public static void main(){
        LinkedList ll = new LinkedList();
        ll.addFirst(8); // Instance method, which should manage the head member
        ll.addFirst(7);
        ll.addFirst(6);
        ll.addFirst(5);
        ll.addFirst(4);
        ll.addFirst(3);
        ll.addFirst(2);
        ll.addFirst(1);
        
        ll.print(); // Instance method
        int m = 2; int n = 2;
        ll.skipMdeleteN(m, n); // No head argument
        ll.print(); // 1->2->5->6->null
    }
}
```

Comment: The loops need to be nested because the Problem is such that - Sample Input : M=2 N=2    LL: 1->2->3->4->5->6->7->8  Sample Output : 1->2->5->6

Comment: Once the outer loop reaches its limit, which is m, we proceed to the next loop of n. but after completing our deletion operation in the n loop, we again need to skip the next m nodes. for which we would need the First loop of m. But here, we are unable to use that loop for a second or third time. OUTPUT of the proposed code as generated in vsCode -                                                    1->2->3->4->5->6->7->8->null
1->2->5->6->7->8->null           The code deleted n nodes the first time(which are 3,4) but prints all the remaining nodes as is

Comment: Are you saying you need to **repeatedly** delete chunks? What is the desired output? In your question you wrote *"The target is to Traverse a Linked List and skip M nodes, then delete N nodes after that"*. There is nothing there that says that this process should be repeated?

Comment: Anyway, I added a version of the method to my answer that repeats the removal of  nodes after every chunk of  nodes. Let me know if this is what you wanted?

Comment: I have updated your question to include this requirement, and the example of expected output you have given here. Please let me know if this is correct?

Comment: Yes, you got the question right. But sorry I cannot see the changes made in the code. Thank you in advance for your patience mate!

Comment: There is a change in the method compared to my previous version. See the loop `while (curr != null)`?

Comment: Got it. Good day mate!